# jquery delegate how to trigger on load of content?

Tags: jquery, ajax, delegates

I need to set up some HTML via jQuery when the page renders. For instance, I may have this:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <div class="theDiv"></div>
        <a class="theLink"...>...</a>
    <li>
<ol>
```

Sometimes I need to hide the div. Sometimes I need to apply a click event to the anchor tag. So I may have this:

```
$('li').hide();
$('a').click(function(){...});
```

That works fine.

However, we're now loading additional LIs to this list. Unfortunately, we're not doing that with jQuery. I could wrap the above in a function that could be called after the ajax loads to re-render everything. But is there a better way?

I was thinking `live()` would be the solution, but I see that `delegate()` is now preferred via the documentation.

Either way, both seem to only allow you to bind events (click, hover, etc.) rather than simply re-render after new HTML is added to the DOM.

Is there a way to do taht via `delegate()`? Is there a more proper way to handle it?

UPDATE:

Perhaps a much simpler way to ask this: To have JS act upon the DOM after an AJAX update, does one have to trigger it via the AJAX call itself (typically via a callback function), or is there a jQuery way to 'watch' for DOM updates and fire off accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

I think the latest jquery API call for this is [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) the 2nd example on the documentation page seems to fit your case exactly.

Comment: Yes, this: on(); is what you want to use. The question I have is whether jQuery can recognize to changes in the DOM that are made by js outside of jQuery. I thought so, but I guess I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code you want to execute in the `success` callback of your AJAX call. Make sure you only run your code on new elements though unless the code won't break anything if it's run on the same element more than once.

Comment: Yea, that seems to be the solution. None of the AJAX is being done via jQuery, unfortunately, so we can't cache/pass any jQuery objects through it which just makes things a little messy.

Comment: Then you should probably refactor some of your code. However, you can simply use `$(some_dom_element)` to wrap a native DOM object in a jQuery object. To test if the code was already executed, you can add some class to it and then use e.g. code like this: `var elements = $('.myDynamicElement:not(.alreadyHandled)').addClass('alreadyHandled');`

Comment: jQuery on() should work with any changes to the DOM even if made y javascript outside of jQuery, I think. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong. @Jason's answer is where I would start.

Comment: @John ~ `.on()` can be fashioned as a `.delegate()` which would work with the `click` event hook, but not for programmatically triggering the `.hide()` call on the `li`. @ThiefMaster makes a better case of answering the question in entirety, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to create a javascript function that utilizes jQuery and is called from within 
whatever javascript you have that is executing the ajax.

Note: After reading it looks live on() only works on events like click and hover as well.

```
function updateMyStuff() {
    $('li').hide();
    $('a').click(function(){...});
}
```

...

```
function myCrazyNonJqueryAjaxWhy?() {
    updateMyStuff();
}
```